# Don't Show if Count<2

Tags: mysql, sql

I im trying to hide and just dysplay the values in Working_On attribute if they are lower than 2. I have tried using WHERE clauses but without luck. I am pretty new to MySQL. Anybody a hand?

This is the table I am using:

```
mysql> SELECT* 
       FROM employee_project;


+------+-------+---------------+
| eNum | pCode | date_assigned |
+------+-------+---------------+
| E246 | P123  | 2014-12-05    |
| E246 | P294  | 2013-11-21    |
| E387 | P123  | 2014-12-20    |
| E403 | P123  | 2015-04-15    |
| E403 | P332  | 2014-04-01    |
| E933 | P294  | 2013-11-21    |
| E933 | P332  | 2014-03-01    |
| E933 | P342  | 2014-12-20    |
+------+-------+---------------+



mysql> SELECT eNum, COUNT(pCOde) as Working_On 
       FROM employee_project 
       GROUP BY eNum;


    +------+------------+
    | eNum | Working_On |
    +------+------------+
    | E246 |          2 |
    | E387 |          1 |
    | E403 |          2 |
    | E933 |          3 |
    +------+------------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below Query will help you

```
SELECT eNum, COUNT(pCOde) as Working_On 
   FROM employee_project 
   GROUP BY eNum;
   HAVING COUNT(pCOde) < 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

To this:

```
SELECT eNum, COUNT(pCOde) as Working_On 
   FROM employee_project 
   GROUP BY eNum;
```

add this:

```
having count(pCode) < 2
```

after the group by clause.   Some database engines will allow you to do this:

```
having working_on < 2
```

but I don't know if mySql is one of those.

Answer (score 2):

You need only to add the HAVING clause which is performed always over an aggregate function:

```
   SELECT eNum, COUNT(pCOde) as Working_On 
   FROM employee_project 
   GROUP BY eNum;
   HAVING COUNT(pCode)<2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use having like this

```
SELECT eNum, COUNT(pCOde) as Working_On 
       FROM employee_project 
       GROUP BY eNum having count(pCode) < 2;
```

The MySQL HAVING clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause. When using with the GROUP BY clause, you can apply a filter condition to the columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause. If the GROUP BY clause is omitted, the MySQL HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause. Notice that the MySQL HAVING clause applies the condition to each group of rows, while the WHERE clause applies the condition to each individual row.

for more information read http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx